# Потокобезопасная кольцевая коллекция

Tags: c#, многопоточность, ienumerator

Нужна коллекция, которая потокобезопасно и по порядку сможет отдавать свои элементы при запросе без их удаления, при достижении конца коллекции, начать отдачу сначала. При этом всём, должна быть возможность добавления новых элементов прямо во время работы с этой коллекцией.
Я сразу обратил внимание на интерфейс IEnumerator. Для потокобезопасности, я выбрал   concurrentbag, т.к в документации написано, что работа с enumerator там реализована потокобезопасно. 
Вопрос в том, что не получается сделать конечный удобный интерфейс для работы с такой коллекцией.

```
public class InfoBag : ConcurrentBag<string>
{
    public IEnumerator<string> Enumerator { get; private set; }

    public InfoBag()
    {
        Enumerator = GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            base.Add(item);
        }

        Enumerator = GetEnumerator();
    }

    public new void Add(string item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        Enumerator = GetEnumerator();
    }

    public string Take()
    {
        if (!Enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Enumerator = GetEnumerator();
            Enumerator.MoveNext();
        }

        return Enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

В этом примере много неудобств, например если нету элементов, коллекция всегда будет возвращать null. И вообще у меня ощущения что я сделал кривой велосипед, есть ли другие пути решения данной задачи или мой пример это норма и такое можно использовать?

Comment: А чего в нем неудобного кроме возвращения null?

Comment: @iluxa1810 не так выразился, на каждое действие, удаление- добавления и т.д будет null, и тут основной вопрос, нормально ли писать такой код и так использовать enumerator.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду ошибка "Коллекция была изменена перечисление невозможно?"

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, и она тоже

Comment: Я проверил и "Коллекция была изменена перечисление невозможно?" у меня не вылетело, в то время, как обычный List падает.

Comment: Не знаю. У меня все нормально работает. Сейчас в LINQPad'e проверил.

Comment: Возможно я что-то не так сделал

Comment: Я вот так тестил  var test=new InfoBag();
 test.Add("1");
 test.Add("2");
 test.Add("3");
 int i=0;
 while(test.Enumerator.MoveNext()){
  Console.WriteLine(test.Enumerator.Current);

Comment: В общем, у меня в тесте почему-то была ранняя версия, с опубликованной тут, всё хорошо, спасибо. В конечную программу вставлю её, а на null уже закрою глаза, не так уж и страшно, главное что работает :)

Comment: В названии указано кольцевая, т.е. вы подразумеваете ограниченный набор элементов? И вам это ещё нужно?

Comment: @Kamushek заголовок отредактировали, я в нём другое писал. Кольцевая значит, что при вызове Take будут последовательно выдаваться элементы, а когда дойдёт до конца, то начать выдачу сначала.